How to use fraction string in Excel/Calc/Sheets as formula
I am having trouble to create a proper solution for following problem.
It shall be possible to enter fractions in a excel cell, which shall be used for further calculations.
Very simplified, it should like this:
       A        B         C
     Value   Fraction   Result
 1   120       1/3      =A1 * B1

I dont want to enter =1/3, because the cell will then display 0,33333.
On one hand, it looks ugly,
on the other, most people will be able to identify 0,333 = 1/3 but 7/5 or 17/4 will be difficult.
I am looking for a solution that works in Excel, OO/LO Calc and Google Sheets.
VBA is out of scope, unfortunately.

I think you need to convert the fraction to decimal.  Like 25% would be .25

Thanks a lot. Thats a perfekt solution for excel and OO calc, but unfortunately it does not work for google sheets.

If you really want to display fractions then, I guess, you could create a table with 1 column showing the fraction while the 2nd column shows the decimal value.  Then in your formula you can use vlookup to find the fraction and use the decimal value.

Choose cells you want to enter fractions in. Right-click -> Format cells... -> Custom -> input #/#
B1:B3 formatted with rule above. Result:


If they are already entered as string then could use-
=A2*LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(B2,"/"),CHOOSECOLS(x,1)/CHOOSECOLS(x,2))


